# Background image with react js - not displaying full screen

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs

I'm used to react native and trying my hand at reactjs, however I'm getting really frustrated with myself as I understand a lot of how react works from using react native but I can't style my components properly as I'm not used to css.

I'm using the ant design UI framework to help me build a small web application, and as of now I have my nav bar along the top of the app but want to set an image below that takes up 100% of the screen and have the height auto set to the aspect ratio.

I'm currently trying this but it doesn't work.

```
<div className="background">
</div>

//In App.css

.background {
  background-image: url('./assets/main-image.jpg');
  background-size: 'contain';
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}
```

I've tried the above but and a few other methods but nothing is working. It appears that the height is dependent upon whatever the content inside the div is. For example, if I place a h1 tag inside the div then I can see the image but only a few pixels in height.

My image is 4000px in width and is landscape. I just want to be able to dynamically display the image depending on screen resolution.

Can someone point me in the right direction?

Thanks

Edit: I've now set my css background class to this and it's nearly there.

```
  background-image: url('./assets/main-image.jpg');
  background-size: contain;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
```

The only issue is now I'm left with a decent size of padding below the image due to it rendering the full height of my view port

Comment: try to set the height to `100vh` and the width to `100vw`

Comment: @GabrielCarneiro thanks for responding. This actually does something different then I'm used to. However the image is enormous and does not appear to be scaling despite me setting the size to 'contain'.

Comment: Try getting rid of the quotes around contain

Comment: @wariofan1 haha I just realised that might be a possibility, just as you posted that. Thankyou! it works, One issue with this however is that by using the vh and vw units, it's making the image repeat as it's using my screen res by the looks of it and not the tab window. Is there any where I can grab the window measurements and use them to set? or set the width and asjust the height dynamically

Comment: What happens when you set both width and height to undefined?

Comment: @juicy89 haha happens to the best of us! you can also set background-repeat: no-repeat to get rid of the repeat, and possibly background-size: stretch ?

Comment: @Rahamin Nothing happens by the looks of it. It's just an empty div. Getting rid of the quotes and setting both height and width to 100vh and 100vw respectively is definitely getting close to my desired result, however these units appear to be grabbing a reference to my overall screen resolution. I'm looking to set the width to the window size and then the height to the aspect ratio of the image.

Comment: Thanks again @wariofan1, the background-repeat: no-repeat is working with regards to moving the duplicated image. I can see that the element however is still taking up the extra space that is set by the viewport units. I'll keep trying to see if I can set the width to just the window size. Thanks again!

Comment: Okay I'm getting close. I'm now setting my background css class to

background-image: url('./assets/main-image.jpg');
  background-size: contain;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;

This is basically nearly there,  the only issue now is that there is quite a bit of padding at the bottom of the image before my next component. Anyone have any ideas how I can eliminate this?

Comment: @juicy89 only other thought I have is that your container is larger than the image dimensions.  I dont think you need height and width 100% and vh, I think your next option is to do background-size: stretch or make your image larger

Answer (score 5):

Try this:

```
position: fixed;
top: 0;
width: 100%;
height: 100%;
background-size: cover;
background-image: url('background.jpg');
```